# Why some cells in Infopath 2013 does't change of color?

Tags: infopath

I have some cells in a table in Infopath that once changed the background color persists this color even if I turn it off, I try to change their color but I couldn't.

any style guide that help me to create a beatiful form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, is very strange but you have to select the color first and then the border, you can't select the border and then the color or only the border.

Comment: GREAT!! - it was driving me crazy.. Changing the color, and then the border (again) fixed the issue... Nice, feature Microsoft. /Morten